Understanding the bit depth of mp3
I'm looking for expertise on mp3 audio files, specifically the mp3 format. Although I'm IT and have managed an Icecast streaming server using darkice client for many years, I inherted from a well-qualified sound engineer being the only one who knows Linux.
According to Darkice, the bit sample rate is 44100 with a bit depth of 16, correct?
[input]
device          = default #hw:1,0
sampleRate      = 44100     # sample rate in Hz. try 11025, 22050 or 44100
bitsPerSample   = 16        # bits per sample. try 16
channel         = 2         # channels. 1 = mono, 2 = stereo

When I use soxi to show details of a recorded audio from the stream using streamripper, I see this:
wmnfadmin@monitor:~$ soxi /nfs/Soundfiles/AV-Issues/wmnf_000000_000001_satbgs1_153.MP3
soxi WARN mp3-util: MAD lost sync

Input File     : '/nfs/Soundfiles/AV-Issues/wmnf_000000_000001_satbgs1_153.MP3'
Channels       : 2
Sample Rate    : 44100
Precision      : 16-bit
Duration       : 00:53:59.89 = 142879149 samples = 242992 CDDA sectors
File Size      : 38.9M
Bit Rate       : 96.0k
Sample Encoding: MPEG audio (layer I, II or III)

However, if I load this same file in Adobe Audition or Audacity, it shows 32-bit float as the bit depth. Can someone help me to understand why? Our audio playback software is having issues ingesting some of this audio and we're told it is because the bit depth is 32-bit and I'm looking for ways to correct the issue.

soxi WARN mp3-util: MAD lost sync could indicate there is an issue with the file

Note that this really isn't a Linux/Unix quesiton.

AFAIK MP3 format support maximum of 16 bits of depth. When I tested with Audacity I saw it convert it to floating point. The reason is sample, with fp you have more "space" for edits w/o loose details in the sample.


Thanks, ok. I think I understand now. Perhaps mp3 doesn't actually have a bit depth. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27652123/how-to-know-the-bit-depth-of-a-mp3-file

Also note that mp3 doesn't even have a fixed bit rate; it can do VBR so the encoder can optimise depending on the input data.  A single track could easily vary from 64kbps to 320kbps!

@rwfitzy MP3 and similar compression format most definitely don't have something like a fixed bit depth. The truncation of coefficients is what really makes up most of the compression; these coefficients are not the time signal, but are used to compute the time signal. Which sample format the resulting time signal then has is 100% choice of the decoder.

I'm still going back and forth with the engineers as they insist the MP3 files we are ingesting have the wrong bit-depth causing our issue. They Google 'is there a bit depth on mp3'? The AI response is 'Yes, MP3 files have bit depth, which is a factor in determining the number of possible amplitude values between the noise floor and 0 dBFS. Bit depth also affects file size and bit rate, which is the amount of data transmitted or received per second. In MP3s, bit rate describes the amount of information used to encode an audio signal.' Does this make sense?
